# ActiveStorage Clone Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, clone, rails-activestorage

I'm working on a Ruby-on-Rails project, using ActiveStorage linked to AWS-S3 for files upload and storage. I use **clowne** gem to clone my objects.

I want to clone an object with attached file, and at the same time, clone also this file (so clone it too in AWS-S3).

I looked long time on Google, and found **clowne_active_storage** gem, to manage ActiveStorage attachments clone.

But my problem is that when I'm trying to clone multiple objects, the clone works well for the first one, and doesn't work for the others.

My User model :

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  MAX_FILE_SIZE = 30.megabytes
  MAX_FILE_SIZE_HR = "30MB" #human readable

  validate :validate_fields

  has_one_attached :file_input

  def has_attachment?
    !self.file_input.attachment().nil?
  end

  private

  def validate_fields
    validate_file_size
  end

  def validate_file_size
    if file_input.attached? && file_input.blob.byte_size > MAX_FILE_SIZE
      file_input.purge
      errors[:base] << ("File size should be less than " + MAX_FILE_SIZE_HR)
    end
  end
end
```

My code to clone multiple objects :

```rb
self.users.each { |user|
  user_copy = UserCloner.call(user).to_record
  user_copy.save!
}
```

The code of my UserCloner class (using **clowne** gem) :

```rb
class UserCloner < Clowne::Cloner
  adapter :active_record
  include_attached :file_input

  # on clone finalize (_source = user & record = user_copy)
  finalize do |_source, record, params|
    if _source.has_attachment?
      # Clone attached file
      record.file_input.attach(_source.file_input.blob)
    end
  end
end
```

So when I clone users, file_input is successfully cloned for the first one, but not for the others. Using debugger, I see something strange :
When i check `file_input` for the 1st cloned user, I have this `Attachment.record` equal to my cloned user (with id = nil because it is before user_copy.save!):

```rb
<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00005646cd9cc3f8 @name="file_input", @record=#<User id: nil...
```

but for the following cloned users, I have `Attachment.record` equal to my source user (_source) and not user_copy:

```rb
<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00005646cd9608d8 @name="file_input", @record=#<User id: 1...
```

I understand that the problem take origin here, but I can't understand why for the 1st cloned user, attachment record is attached to cloned user, and for the following, to the original user.

If someone encountered the same problem, or have a beginning of solution, i'll take it merrily!

Thank you very much for your help in advance,
Have a nice day,
Pierre Avinain

Comment: I'm guessing that issue is down to the implementation details of `UserCloner`. Also you might try cloning the blob: `new_blob = _source.file_input.blob.dup; new_blob.key = nil; new_blob.save!; record.file_input.attach(new_blob)`